# how do i find out my "openid"

Tags: find, openid

i can't log in now without having to use another site like google because instead of asking for my email and password, it now asks for my "openid" and gives a long cryptic website address as an example. I don't see an "openid" for me in my account area. more and more i'm being forced to go through google to log into my accounts on various sites and i hate having to do so. the stack overflow "contact" link doesn't actually contact anyone, it just takes you to a page to post your question. how do i find out my "openid"?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're misunderstanding **OpenID**. You have an "openid" if you have an account with an OpenID provider - like [Google, Yahoo!, PayPal, BBC, AOL, LiveJournal, MySpace, IBM, Steam, Sherdog, Orange and VeriSign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID).

It works by having you log in to the account with your provider, which then verifies your identity with another service which requested the authentication, like stackoverflow. **So stackoverflow doesn't know that you are 'michael' but it does know that google says you are michael - which is why you need to log in to google.**

If you want a stackoverflow username/password, you can do so from your profile page --> **my logins** --> add more logins --> **"To create a new Stack Exchange account" ... click here**.